# Detect the volume key press in background

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I implemented a background service for getting the sensor data in the log. i am getting the volume press event in `dispatchKeyEvent()` method in the activity. But, i want to get the data even though the application is in background.

I tried with `BroadcastReceiver`.

While click the volume key button, it should trigger a method when the application is in background(like the `mediaplayer` app increase/decrease the sound).

Comment: Try this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829791/how-to-syncronize-system-volume-with-mediaplayer-app/55829839#55829839

Comment: Mayur ,I don't want to increase the volume. i wanted to detect the key press.